# Automatically map mobile devices to drive letter?

Tags: windows, storage, ios, android

Evening community.

I'm in the process of developing a windows based application which heavily revolves around mobiles being connected to a machine via USB, Currently. The communication between android using googles ADB drivers works without a problem (currently, that is). The problem is getting said application to integrate well with IOS users.

*What the application does* I'm bascially reinventing the wheel of stock control for a client, who wants a completely customized application based around their current mobile barcode scanner which scans and saves the scanned items to a file name created with the date & Time in a text format. This application is both on IOS and Android devices.

What i'm looking to do, is have their current machine automatically map the connected device to a drive letter to allow easier browsing of the device through the application & Pull the necessary file and save locally to then make other changes as needed..

So, the overall question. Is, that without having a jailbroken/rooted mobile device to allow Mass Storage, is it possible to have a Windows XP based machine to automatically map connected IOS and Android devices to a drive letter? There will be only one device connected at one time

Comment: `is it possible to have a Windows XP based machine` XP's out of support and end of life. Time for your client to upgrade. Well, past time, but whatever.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Even know Windows XP is out of support, they use drivers and applications which was designed for Windows XP & on their migration attempt to Windows 7, the drivers which are used in a Paragon Quiz Machine for example. Worked, but with extremely limited abilities. Even when running in compatibility mode, so upgrading on the Workshop machines are a little out of the question.

Comment: Have the SE guys restored the site from a 90's backup?

Comment: `so upgrading on the Workshop machines are a little out of the question` They'll have to sooner or later. Sooner is cheaper and easier. If your client wants to shoot themselves in the foot, and you want to charge money to help them blow their foot off, that's your business, but I wouldn't expect much in the way of help around here.

Comment: @hopelessn00b sorry for the delay, I haven't suggested charging this company for the software, as I work for them full time & it's not shooting them in the foot with using a windows xp based workshop machine, as it works efficiently with the software they use. Perhaps out of support, but it's imho doing no harm with sticking to legacy operating systems